# background mode plugin_not_installed , even background mode plugin is already installed in ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

background mode "plugin_not_installed", even background mode plugin is already installed in ionic project

error Showing in console

```
 {
[ng]   "error": "plugin_not_installed"
[ng]
```

}

my package.json details

```
//   "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.30.0",
//  "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
// "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.15",
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note :- platform.ready() is the trick** ,
put the code inside platform.ready() function

```
constructor(private platform: Platform,private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode){

     platform.ready().then(() => {
          console.log("background mode off")
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
          console.log("background mode check",this.backgroundMode.isActive(), this.backgroundMode.isEnabled(),this.backgroundMode.isScreenOff);
    
          // this.backgroundMode.enable();
    
          console.log("-------------------->", this.backgroundMode.isEnabled());
          console.log("-------------------->", this.backgroundMode.isActive());
    
          this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(()=>{
                    
            console.log("background mode on");
            
          });
        });

}
```